# Using collections in Knockout, what is the best approach for iteration?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm at a crossroads, I wanted to iterate server-side so I could have Google indexability.

It seems as though KO was designed to be used as an iterator and if you try to use server-side iteration you run into a lot of issues?

E.G If I loop through "people" in knockout, it's easy to have a reference to the iterating index. But if your iterating with server-side, and then you try to:

```
<li><span data-bind="text: myPropertyOnItem"</span></li>
```

How do you get the reference of the iterating item? 
EDIT: I do know how, but it is very untidy!
e.g: `data-bind="click: function(data,event) { ThingListVM.getThingByID(data,event, @Thing.ID).voteUp() }"`

**What is the best/most-commonly implemented solution, is it to iterate using KO?**

Thank you!

Comment: KO and other client side SPA frameworks do everything on the client side. All data comes in via ajax, this does mean that you have to handle how Google would index the content differently, and that depends on your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KO and other client side SPA frameworks do everything on the client side. All data comes in via ajax, this does mean that you have to handle how Google would index the content differently, and that depends on your application.

Have a look at these two articles for more information:

If you have a completely knockout based solution you can get Google to help you out: http://www.webseoanalytics.com/blog/googles-ajax-crawling-scheme-and-its-effects-on-seo/

Keep in mind that only works for Google though, I haven't found any silver bullet for this one yet.

If you're using knockout to enhance your site you'll need to send the content along twice or try [dual side templating](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Dual-Side_Templating). I'm not sure if that's easy to setup with knockout though.